# Is a 1D or 2D array more computationally efficient in Lua for a large matrix?

Tags: matrix, optimization, lua, runtime

In **Lua specifically**, which is the least computationally expensive: a matrix in which an item found at (row, column) is located at `matrix[row][column]` or is located at `matrix[row + numberOfRows * column]`?

Assume that these items will be **read and written to a lot**, and assume that the matrix is **large** at about 1000 by 2000 items.

I mainly care about efficiency in the moment rather than overhead.

Comment: Usually 1d is either better or the same, but you could profile both ways with your use case to be certain

Comment: There are lots of factors that could affect the speed. Tables are usually implemented with an array part, so if you have no nils in there, accessing any element is O(1) anyway. Using tables, you will have a higher amount of GC-managed objects, resulting in higher pressure on the GC, and memory fragmentation. However, you will need to measure this instead of taking random guesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown below, `matrix[row][column]` uses one less VM instruction than `matrix[row + numberOfRows * column]`. However, it is not clear whether one `GETTABLE` is faster than `MUL+ADD`.

The only real answer is: measure both alternatives.

```
$ cat 1
local matrix,row,numberOfRows,column
return matrix[row][column]

$ luac -l 1
main <1:0,0> (5 instructions at 0x7f9459c03d40)
0+ params, 5 slots, 1 upvalue, 4 locals, 0 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] LOADNIL     0 3
    2   [2] GETTABLE    4 0 1
    3   [2] GETTABLE    4 4 3
    4   [2] RETURN      4 2
    5   [2] RETURN      0 1

$ cat 2
local matrix,row,numberOfRows,column
return matrix[row + numberOfRows * column]

$ luac -l 2
main <2:0,0> (6 instructions at 0x7ff339c03d40)
0+ params, 5 slots, 1 upvalue, 4 locals, 0 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] LOADNIL     0 3
    2   [2] MUL         4 2 3
    3   [2] ADD         4 1 4
    4   [2] GETTABLE    4 0 4
    5   [2] RETURN      4 2
    6   [2] RETURN      0 1
```

However, a loop like this

```
for row=1,numberOfRows do
    for column=1,numberOfColumns do
        matrix[row][column]=f(row,column)
    end
end
```

is probably slower than this

```
for row=1,numberOfRows do
    local r=matrix[row]
    for column=1,numberOfColumns do
        r[column]=f(row,column)
    end
end
```

Again, measure both alternatives.